# Targeting a Shadow DOM element without breaking forwards compatibility

Tags: css, angular, dom, css-selectors, shadow-dom

I am attempting to target an Angular Shadow DOM element created by mat-menu like so:

```
$google: #133700

.mat-menu-content {
    background-color: $google;
}
```

However, this doesn't work. I am told that the `/deep` CSS selector may help with this (it's just a case of adding the `/deep/` selector to the above?) but `/deep/` is being deprecated, to the point where by the time the software is ready it might already be incompatible with modern browsers, so it's not really an appropriate solution at the moment. Can anyone suggest an alternative way to target a Shadow DOM element in Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/deep/` is being deprecated from the CSS standards. The Angular equivalent is `::ng-deep`. It will pierce through emulated encapsulation (but not native, of course).

```
::ng-deep .mat-menu-content {
    background-color: $google;
}
```